# jQuery won't set and get the same value

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete

I have a problem with setting a text field value and then using it again with jquery.

I have 2 input fields that I am using with jQuery autocomplete:

```
<input type="text" name="AccountName" id="AccountName" size="50">
<input type="text" id="NewAccountId" name="NewAccountId" value="0">
```

When I call the autocomplete for this field, it enters the Account Id into the NewAccountId field.  I know that works; you can see it on screen.  The code is:

```
$(function() 
  {$("#AccountName").autocomplete({
      source: "../cfc/ajax_code.cfc?method=AccountSearchId",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function(event, ui) {
              $('#NewAccountId').val(ui.item.custid);
              ContactListUpdate(this.MyCustId);}  });  });
```

When I go to the next field, I have another call to the database via an autocomplete.

```
<input type="text" name="TransactionName" id="TransactionName" size="20">
```

The jquery function is:

```
$(function() 
  {$("#TransactionName").autocomplete({
    source: "../cfc/ajax_code.cfc?method=TransactionLookUp&MyCustomerId="+$("#NewAccountId").val(),
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#MyTransactionId').val(ui.item.transid);} }); });
```

So here is my problem...

When I get my account name, it actually sets my id in the NewAccountId field.  However, when I run the Transaction auto complete, it gets the original load value from the NewAccountId field (which is usually "0") rather than the value from the first function.  I know the code works because in FireFox if I refresh the form with a value in the NewAccountId field, the code will use that value to filter my transaction id's by.

After scouring help sites for 2 days, the closest answer I found was that boolean dirty flag value wasn't changing but haven't found how to override this.  I have tried updating the field with the following options, to no avail:

```
this.MyCustId = $("#NewAccountId").val();
document.getElementById('NewAccountId').setAttribute('value',this.MyCustId);
```

or

```
this.MyCustId = $("#NewAccountId").val();
document.getElementById('MyTestId').value = this.MyCustId;
```

Both of these options set the field value but doesn't change the original field value.

And to add insult to injury, as you can see in the first auto complete function I call the ContactListUpdate javascript - not jquery - function.  This calls an update that changes the contact in a select list.  It uses the new account id.  It works!

Also, after I submit the form, the value in the data field is exactly what I want it to be.  It is only not working when I call the script to get the transaction.

HELP!  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the second autocomplete in the callback of the first. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    function setAutoComplete() {
        $("#TransactionName").unbind();
        $("#TransactionName").autocomplete({
            source: "../cfc/ajax_code.cfc?method=TransactionLookUp&MyCustomerId=" + $("#NewAccountId").val(),
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#MyTransactionId').val(ui.item.transid);
            }
        });
    }

    $("#AccountName").autocomplete({
        source: "../cfc/ajax_code.cfc?method=AccountSearchId",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#NewAccountId').val(ui.item.custid);
            ContactListUpdate(this.MyCustId);

            setAutoComplete();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting, it only half works.  So when I selected my customer then tried to select the transaction, it work.  However, then I changed the customer and the transaction selection/autocomplete didn't even work at all, let alone get the right transaction.  So now I am half way there!

Answer (score 0):

The code to instrument the autocomplete on the TransactionName field executes on page ready. At that time the value of the NewAccountId field is always `0`, so the string you provide for the "source" option always includes `0`.

You need to provide a callback function for the "source" option, which will be called when the autocomplete executes.

Try:

```
$("#TransactionName").autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response) {
        $.get("../cfc/ajax_code.cfc", {
            term: request.term,
            method: "TransactionLookUp",
            MyCustomerId: $("#NewAccountId").val()
        }, function(data) { response(data); });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#MyTransactionId').val(ui.item.transid);
    }
});
```

Comment: I get what your saying.  However, this ended in the same results.  While the page might load with NewAccountId equal to "0", the first function change the display value but not the underlying value.  This worked exactly as I have implemented.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user3144834 - As my answer states, you definitely had an issue in your original code and the code in my answer addresses it. If it still isn't working for you, there must be something else wrong that you need to debug. Start by checking the value of the input just before the call to `$.get()`.

Comment: Actually, John, this did not work.  I went back and retested.  The autocomplete adds a URL parameter of "term" to the web call.  Your code drops the term parameter and I need to put it back in.  Now the question is, how?  On the good side, it does seem to be grabbing the right ID from NewAccountId - which was my problem in the first place.

Comment: So I changed the GET source to: "../cfc/ajax_code.cfc?method=TransactionLookUp&term="+$("#TransactionName").val(),"  This took care of the "term" parameter.  Using the FF debugger, I can see the call parameters and I can see the returned results.  Now the results won't list.

This option is getting closer to working.

Comment: @user3144834 - I see from the autocomplete documentation that the "term" parameter is automatically included when "source" is a string, but not when it is a callback function. I updated the `$.get()` call in my answer to include the "term" parameter.

Comment: @user3144834 - Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DF9mh/) that demonstrates this working as close as it can.

Comment: Your changes for term and method talk to the DB.  However, when you start typing in the TransactionName field, the autocomplete doesn't show any options.  It didn't work in the jfiddle example, either.  THOUGHTS?  Thanks!

Comment: @user3144834 - The jsfiddle works for me. Of course, the only two options are "abc" and "abd", so they show only if you type "ab". I can only guess that there's something wrong with the data returned by the ajax call. Perhaps the format of the returned data is off by a bit.

Comment: You were right, the jsfiddle worked.  I forgot about minlength and was only typing 1 character.  Before your suggested changes, the "pop-up" worked with the returned data (I needed your changes because of the wrong ID being sent).  I'll experiment more tomorrow but I TOTALLY appreciate what you have shared with me!